# C line 34 : Error conflicting types for 'print' in the user defined function print

Tags: c

in the user defined function print if I have the return type as ast I am getting an error as stated in the question title. If I change the written type to void it runs and complies successfully but nothing is being printed. Please help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "stack.h"
#define IO_SIZE 128

typedef char* ast;

ast fgets(ast str, int str_len, FILE* stream);

ast read(ast input)
{
    input[0] = '\0';
    fgets(input, IO_SIZE, stdin);
    input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';
    return input;
}

ast eval(ast parsed)
{
    printf("in eval %s\n",parsed);
    if(strcmp(parsed, ":EXIT"))
    {
        return '0';
    }
    else
    {
        print(parsed);
        return '1';
    }
}

ast print(ast result)
{
    printf("here");
    printf("%s\n",*result);
}

int main()
{
    char my_array[IO_SIZE];
    do
    {
        printf("> ");
        read(my_array);
        printf("in do while loop %s\n",my_array);
    }
    while(eval(my_array));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are using your own declarations of names of standard C functions?

Comment: please don't tag c and c++ unless you are genuinely using both languages. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Don't "fix" problems in your questions. That will make the question and all answers useless.

Comment: Also, when asking questions about build messages, please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build output, *as text*, into the question. And add comments on the lines where you get them. And you should be getting *plenty* of messages.

Comment: As for the likely problem in the title (which should really be a short summary of the question inside the main body), you seem to have forgotten that all symbols must be *declared* before they are used. But this isn't the only problem in your code.

Comment: The function `print`has apparently not been declared when you call it (or you left out relevant parts of your code). Solve this by declaring a function prototype in advance. Study how functions work in your favourite C book.

Comment: I changed the print and defined it before the function eval. I am not getting error but nothing is being printed. If I want to return something do I need to catch it when print is being called from eval?

Comment: You have an answer for the initial version of your code. If you want to discuss code which incorporates that answer please ask a new one. Changing questions so that existing answers are invalidated is not appreciated.

Comment: The problem I was facing was for the edited version of the code. I uploaded the wrong one. Also in the initial version I still get the error after making necessary changes. Nothing is being printed inside the function print.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
ast print(ast result)
{
    printf("here");
    printf("%s\n",*result);
}
```

given

```
typedef char* ast;
```

is undefined behavior. You're telling `printf()` to expect a string, then pass a single character by dereferencing `result`.

It should probably be

```
printf("%s\n", result);
```

but I have not tested it.

Comment: By mistake I uploaded the wrong code. Even with printf("%s\n", result); I get the same error

Comment: @VrajShah When creating a [mcve], please make sure it only replicates the problem you actually ask about. For example by actually building it (with extra warnings enabled).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the link. I will keep that in mind when I post next time